Next-auth signIn return {error:'Configuration'} in responce for invalid credentials. Next JS 14.2.3, Next-auth 5.0.0 Beta
I just started to learn Next JS. I started with Next Js version 14.2.3 and I want to create a login form. I am using next-auth 5.0.0 beta for authentication. I am able to login in with correct credentials. But i want to return a message for user when the credentials are not matching.
I am getting the object {error: 'configuration', status: 200, Ok...} and I have this line in the server console:
[auth][error] CallbackRouteError: Read more at https://errors.authjs.dev#callbackrouteerror
[auth][cause]: Error: Missing credentials.
    at Object.authorize (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./src/util/AuthOptions.ts:44:27)

....
Here is my codes:
API Route
 // src/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts
 export { GET, POST} from "@/util/AuthOptions";

Auth option file:
    // src/util/AuthOptions.ts
import User from "@/app/models/User";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";

const validateEmail = (email: string): boolean => {
const emailRegex = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|("."))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
return emailRegex.test(String(email).toLowerCase());
};

interface Credentials {
username: string;
password: string;
}

const authOptions = {
// Configure one or more authentication providers
providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
    // The credentials provider is used to generate a session
    credentials: {
        username: { label: "Username", type: "text" },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
    },

    async authorize(credentials: Credentials) {
        const { username, password } = credentials;

        if (!validateEmail(username)) {
        throw new Error("Invalid email format.");
        }

        if (!username || !password) {
        throw new Error("Missing credentials.");
        }

        const user = new User();
        const foundUser = await user.getFirst({ username });

        if (foundUser && (await bcrypt.compare(password, foundUser.password))) {
        return { id: foundUser.id, username: foundUser.username };
        } else {
        throw new Error("Invalid credentials.");
        }
    },
    }),
],

// JWT configuration for session management
jwt: {
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
    maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60, // 30 days
},

// Callbacks for customizing JWT and session objects
callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
    if (user) {
        token.user = { id: user.id, username: user.username };
    }
    return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
    session.user = token.user;
    return session;
    },
},

// Enable debug mode in development environment
debug: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development",

// Set session storage using JWT
session: { jwt: true },

// Define custom pages for authentication flows
pages: {
    signIn: "/auth/login",
    signOut: "/auth/signout",
    error: "/auth/login",
},

// Database connection string (if applicable)
database: process.env.Database_URL,
};

export const { handlers:{GET,POST}, signIn, signOut, auth } = NextAuth(authOptions);

Login form
"use client";
import { getCsrfToken, signIn } from "next-auth/react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function LoginForm() {
  const [csrfToken, setCsrfToken] = useState("");
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [error, setError] = useState(null); 

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    setError(null); // Clear error on submit

    if (!username) {
      setError("Username is required");
      return;
    }

    // if (!password) {
    //   setError("Password is required");
    //   return;
    // }

    const res = await signIn("credentials", {
      redirect: false,
      username,
      password,
      csrfToken,
    });

    if (res.error) {
      setError(res.error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchToken = async () => {
      const token = await getCsrfToken();
      setCsrfToken(token);
    };
    fetchToken();
  }, []);

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} method="post">
      <div data-mdb-input-init className="form-outline mb-4">
        <input type="hidden" name="csrfToken" value={csrfToken} />
        <input
          type="email"
          id="username"
          className="form-control"
          name="username"
          value={username}
          onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
          aria-label="Username"
        />
        <label className="form-label" htmlFor="username">Email address</label>
      </div>

      <div data-mdb-input-init className="form-outline mb-4">
        <input
          type="password"
          id="password"
          className="form-control"
          placeholder="Keep it blank"
          name="password"
          value={password}
          onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
          aria-label="Password" 
        />
        <label className="form-label" htmlFor="password">Password</label>
      </div>

      {error && <p className="text-bg-danger">{error}</p>}
      <div className="form-check d-flex justify-content-center mb-4">
        <input
          className="form-check-input me-2"
          type="checkbox"
          id="keepLogin"
          name="keepLogin"
        />
        <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="keepLogin">Remember me</label>
      </div>

      <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary btn-block mb-4">Login</button>
    </form>
  );
}

export default LoginForm;

Thank for any instructions in advance.

For more information: this is the response object:
{"error":"Configuration","code":null,"status":200,"ok":true,"url":null}
and also this is the .env.local:
NEXTAUTH_SECRET= bb5f1a9ea6bb945fd094267f28391794a6ee916353657eaf7cce06b1c654bd4f
NEXTAUTH_URL=http://localhost:3000

Finally I was able to send my custom error to client side. Here is a sample code. Please share you comments with me.
This is the api at /src/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts
import { handlers } from "@auth";
export const { GET, POST } = handlers

I create a actions file to get the client side data and response accordingly.
/src/app/lib/actions.ts
"use server"

import { signIn } from "../../lib/Authenticator";

export async function authenticate(formData: any) {
    try {
        const session = await signIn('credentials', formData)
        return { success: true, message: 'login successful' };

    } catch (err: any) {
        if (err.type === "AuthError") {
            return { 
                error: { message: err.message }
            }
        }
        return { error: { message: 'Failed to login', error: err } }
    }
}

On the auth.ts file I create a custom error class and throw an instance of the class with my message.
/auth.ts
import NextAuth, { AuthError } from "next-auth"
import Credentials from "next-auth/providers/credentials"

class customError extends AuthError {
    constructor(message: string) {
        super()
        this.message = message
    }
}

export const { handlers, signIn, signOut,auth } = NextAuth({
    providers: [
        Credentials({
            credentials: {
                email: {},
                password: {},
            },
            async authorize(credentials) {
                throw new customError("This account is not locked. Please contact your administrator.")
            },
        })
    ],

    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
})

Finally I am getting the message in the login form.
/src/app/login/page.tsx
"use client"

import { authenticate } from "@/app/controllers/Auth";
import { useState } from "react"

export default function SignIn() {

    const [error, setError] = useState('');
    const handleSubmit = async (event: any) => {
        event.preventDefault()
        try {
            const res = await authenticate({
                email: event.target.email.value,
                password: event.target.password.value
            });

            if (res.message === "Login successful") {
                window.location.href = "/dashboard"
            }

            if (res.error) {
                setError(res.error?.message)
            }

        } catch (error: any) {
            setError('Failed to login')
        }
    }

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} method="post">
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" />
            <label  htmlFor="email">Email address</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password"/>
            <label className="form-label" htmlFor="password">Password</label>
            {error && <p className="text-bg-danger">{error}</p>}
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary btn-block mb-4">Login</button>
        </form>
    );
}


thanks, very thanks, my code finally work

Thanks a lot! 10000000x better than the Authjs docs.

I actually don't believe the amount of shit we have to go through to return errors to the client on signIn. Actually insane this lib is the industry standard for authentication on NextJS and it's SO bad. That being said, thank you, this helped a lot.
